# A functional way to count positive integers using 2 symbols

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to know if the following has a name, has been studied, etc. It is a little general question, but I don't know how to find references. I can delete this message if it is off-topic ;)

I first begin with an example to make things explicit.

We define $f : x \mapsto 10 \times x$ (from $\mathbb{N}^*$ to $\mathbb{N}^*$).

Now, for an integer, for example $3402$, we can rewrite it with this composition of functions:

$$ 3402 = 2+10 \times (10 \times (4+(10 \times 3))) = 2+f(f(4+f(3))).$$

Using only $f$ and $1$, we obtain:

$$3402 = 1+1+f(f(1+1+1+1+f(1+1+1))).$$

We can use a convenient notation to make this smaller: $1+1$ can be written down $11$; $f(1)$ can be written down $f1$; $f(1+f(1))$ as $f1f1$; etc. And we get:

$$ 3402 = 11ff1111f111$$

(Of course, in the last equality, on the left is in base 10 notation, and on the right with the new notation; Also, the way to compact it works because we always replace the parentheses the same way).

---

We can use $h : x \mapsto 2 \times x$ to get something related to the binary representation of integers; but we could also take any function from $\mathbb{N}^*$ to $\mathbb{N}^*$.

Of course, all this is not a proper definition, because there is not a unique way to do the decomposition ($10$ can be $f(1)$ or $1+1...+1$ ten times). We could define some cost by taking the length in the *convenient notation* representation (even like this, it may not be unique for a general function, for example $2 = h(1) = 1+1$ so it can be represented as $h1$ and $11$ which are both with cost $2$).

If we take $g$ defined by: $g(1)=4$, $g(2)=6$, $g(4)=7$ (and as we want for other positive integers), then we only need $3$ or less elements to represent each of the seven first positive integers:

$$1=1;~~2=11;~~3=111;~~4=g1;~~5=1g1;~~6=g11;~~7=gg1.$$

(As before, on the left it is in base 10 notation, and on the right with the new notation).

---

My question again: **I would like to know if this way of counting has a name and where it has been studied**.
(For know I just can recall about Horner's method which has some similarities, but for polynomial functions).